# div {position:absolute} renders at different locations on different width screens

Tags: jquery, css, sliding-window

I have made a sliding (S) window with jQuery `animate()` function. i.e. it slides left and right.

```
$.animate({width:'toggle', opacity:'toggle'},2000,'swing',function(){
    // ...
})
```

It uses the following CSS when open.

```
position:absolute;
height: 496px;
width: 694px;
left:36px;
top:124px;
```

The problem I am facing is: on screens with different widths the window starts at different locations. I am supposed to show it adjacent to another window (A). On my laptop it works fine. On client side, it overlaps half of window A. I believe it is due to `position:absolute;` but I don't know how to solve it. Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for the answers guys! Much appreciated.

@ali-youhannaei's Answer gave me an idea to use the following code:

```
var pos = jQuery("#div_a").offset(); // Window A's position
var x = pos.left + jQuery("#div_a").width(); // Window S's position
```

Set `left:x;` with `postion:absolute;` for Window S. That will work.

Answer (score 2):

Different sized screens have different resolutions. So, on your computer 100px may be the center of your screen but on someone else's it may not. Using a % instead of px may work better for you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use  `$("body").height();` and also `$("body").scrollTop()` to get the client window height and position of page to view, in your code you have your slides height. decrease your slide height from them. you can now show your slide in center of page. like this:

```
var top = $("body").scrollTop() + ((parseInt($("body").height()) - slideHeight) / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try

```
float:right;
```

to float that object just along side your window. 
You'll need to post whole code here for me to tell the division tag's placement though.
Otherwise you may search for float property at [W3Schools](http://w3schools.com)

Comment: nope. instead of absolute use float as % messes up sometimes especially on screens of different aspect ratios. The div tag would need to be placed in html accordingly then.

Answer (score 0):

If this div where the animation or the position:absolute property is applied has a parent div, then apply position:relative.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="slider"></div>
</div>

css:
.wrapper{ position:relative;}
.slider{
position:absolute;
height: 496px;
width: 694px;
left:36px;
top:124px;
}
```